# Laravel - Mysql get elements from join table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting the total carOwnerDept(department id) from **cars** table which has relation with **department** table
but i can't get the issue from **cars** table.

Here's the code

```
$dept = DB::table('department')
->select('department.name', DB::raw('COUNT(cars.carOwnerDept) AS dept_count'))
->join('cars', 'department.id', '=', 'cars.carOwnerDept')
->select('department.name', 'cars.issue')
->groupBy('department.name')
->where('cars.carType', '=', 'Internal Customer')
->whereDate('cars.created_at', '>=', $from)
->whereDate('cars.created_at', '<=', $to)
->get();
```

Views

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Issues</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach($dept as $depts)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$depts->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$depts->issue}}</td>
    <td>{{$depts->dept_count}}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```

DB Structure

**cars**

id   |  carOwnerDept | issue
1       1              barcode problem
2       3              scanner problem
3       2              barcode problem

**department**

id   | name
1      QA
2      PP
3      PE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the number of car owner departments as shown below.

```
$dept = DB::table('department')
        ->select(DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(carOwnerDept) FROM cars WHERE carOwnerDept=department.id) AS dept_count'))
        ->join('cars', 'department.id', '=', 'cars.carOwnerDept')
        ->select('department.name', 'cars.issue')
        ->where('cars.carType', '=', 'Internal Customer')
        ->whereDate('cars.created_at', '>=', $from)
        ->whereDate('cars.created_at', '<=', $to)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Getting error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cars.issue' in 'field list' (SQL: select `department`.`name`, `cars`.`issue` from `department` :(

Comment: @Suvin94 you'll need to join the tables from which you need to fetch data. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
$dept = DB::table('department')
->join('cars', 'department.id', '=', 'cars.carOwnerDept')
->select('department.name', DB::raw('COUNT(cars.carOwnerDept) AS dept_count'), 'cars.issue')
->where('cars.carType', '=', 'Internal Customer')
->whereDate('cars.created_at', '>=', $from)
->whereDate('cars.created_at', '<=', $to)
->groupBy('department.name')
->get();
```

Comment: Getting an error Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cars.cars.issue' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `department`.`name`, COUNT

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend that you create functions on your models so that you don't need to input raw queries. Fewer codes and easier to understand.